# Generate service client from a Java webservice which has MTOM enabled

Tags: wcf

I am using the VS 2013 with the .net 4.5.2
I am building an application consuming a Java web service.

The point is that I don't have direct access to the service for now, I cannot "add service reference" from the Visual Studio. I just have the wsdl and all xsd files in local drive.

I want to have a service client to invoke the service. Can I use the svcutil.exe to generate the code? Please advise the command syntax.

Second, I am highlighted that the Java web service has the MTOM enabled at server side and I have to "enable the MTOM from client side" while invoking functions! What i need to do? How to achieve that?

Comment: thanks John, can you advise how to enable MTOM from the client side?

Comment: Disagree with @JohnSaunders comment - "Add Service Reference" won't create MTOM bindings automatically

Comment: @mgorgon the OP said two separate things and I addressed one of them.

Comment: @mgorgon see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209.aspx to manually enable mtom.